# Error query for a user does not come out in consultation OneToMany if given a condition

Tags: symfony

First, forgive me for my bad English.

I have a problem with an sql query that I am doing using doctrine in symfony

I have two related tables, one of users and one of actions performed by the user, these tables are related from one to many, a user can do many actions.
I am trying to make a query in which I from all users who have not done an action (the status column is the one that indicates the types of actions, when the process ends it will have an 8) therefore I want to remove those that do not have an 8. In principle, although I have tried many options, what I think would be more correct would be

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from("BackendBundle:Inscritos", "e")
            ->select("e")
             ->innerJoin("BackendBundle:InscritosAcciones", "u", "WITH", "e.id=u.inscritosId")
             ->groupBy("u.inscritosId")
            ->where("u.status != 8")
            ->getQuery();
```

The fact is that as the user has some other action besides that of status 8 (must have them since it is a process and the actions allow to see what has been happening) I continue to remove that user.

my entities

```
namespace BackendBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * Inscritos
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"correoUsuario"}, message="¡Este correo ya esta registrado!")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"documento"}, message="¡Este numero de documento ya esta registrado!")
 */
class Inscritos {

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Por favor, escribe tu nombre")
 */
private $nombreUsuario;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Por favor, escribe tus apellidos")
 */
private $apellidoUsuario;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Range(
 *      min = 9,
 *      max = 9,
 *      minMessage = "Este campo tiene que tener  {{ limit }} numeros ",
 *      maxMessage = "Este campo tiene que tener  {{ limit }} numeros  "
 * )
 */
private $telefono;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\Email(checkMX=true)
 */
private $correoUsuario;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $validadocorreo = 'NO';

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $tipodocumento;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Por favor, escribe tu numero de documento")
 */
private $documento;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Por favor, escribe tu fecha de nacimiento")
 */
private $fechanacimiento;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $pais;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $provinciaotros;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $municipiootros;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Por favor, escribe tu codigo postal")
 */
private $codigopostal;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Por favor, escribe tu direccion de contacto")
 */
private $direccion;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $lugarparticipacion;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $fechainscritpcion;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $ipinscripcion;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $cadenaseg;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $bloqueo = 'no';

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $razonBloqueo;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $perfil;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $fechaControl;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $idMunicipio;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $idProvincia;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $idCcaa;

public function __toString() {
    return (string) $this->getId();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set nombreUsuario
 *
 * @param string $nombreUsuario
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setNombreUsuario($nombreUsuario) {
    $this->nombreUsuario = $nombreUsuario;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nombreUsuario
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNombreUsuario() {
    return $this->nombreUsuario;
}

/**
 * Set apellidoUsuario
 *
 * @param string $apellidoUsuario
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setApellidoUsuario($apellidoUsuario) {
    $this->apellidoUsuario = $apellidoUsuario;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get apellidoUsuario
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getApellidoUsuario() {
    return $this->apellidoUsuario;
}

/**
 * Set telefono
 *
 * @param string $telefono
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setTelefono($telefono) {
    $this->telefono = $telefono;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get telefono
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTelefono() {
    return $this->telefono;
}

/**
 * Set correoUsuario
 *
 * @param string $correoUsuario
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setCorreoUsuario($correoUsuario) {
    $this->correoUsuario = $correoUsuario;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get correoUsuario
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCorreoUsuario() {
    return $this->correoUsuario;
}

/**
 * Set validadocorreo
 *
 * @param string $validadocorreo
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setValidadocorreo($validadocorreo) {
    $this->validadocorreo = $validadocorreo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get validadocorreo
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getValidadocorreo() {
    return $this->validadocorreo;
}

/**
 * Set tipodocumento
 *
 * @param string $tipodocumento
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setTipodocumento($tipodocumento) {
    $this->tipodocumento = $tipodocumento;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tipodocumento
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTipodocumento() {
    return $this->tipodocumento;
}

/**
 * Set documento
 *
 * @param string $documento
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setDocumento($documento) {
    $this->documento = $documento;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get documento
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDocumento() {
    return $this->documento;
}

/**
 * Set fechanacimiento
 *
 * @param \DateTime $fechanacimiento
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setFechanacimiento($fechanacimiento) {
    $this->fechanacimiento = $fechanacimiento;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get fechanacimiento
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getFechanacimiento() {
    return $this->fechanacimiento;
}

/**
 * Set pais
 *
 * @param string $pais
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setPais($pais) {
    $this->pais = $pais;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get pais
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPais() {
    return $this->pais;
}

/**
 * Set provinciaotros
 *
 * @param string $provinciaotros
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setProvinciaotros($provinciaotros) {
    $this->provinciaotros = $provinciaotros;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get provinciaotros
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getProvinciaotros() {
    return $this->provinciaotros;
}

/**
 * Set municipiootros
 *
 * @param string $municipiootros
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setMunicipiootros($municipiootros) {
    $this->municipiootros = $municipiootros;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get municipiootros
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMunicipiootros() {
    return $this->municipiootros;
}

/**
 * Set codigopostal
 *
 * @param string $codigopostal
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setCodigopostal($codigopostal) {
    $this->codigopostal = $codigopostal;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get codigopostal
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCodigopostal() {
    return $this->codigopostal;
}

/**
 * Set direccion
 *
 * @param string $direccion
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setDireccion($direccion) {
    $this->direccion = $direccion;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get direccion
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDireccion() {
    return $this->direccion;
}

/**
 * Set lugarparticipacion
 *
 * @param string $lugarparticipacion
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setLugarparticipacion($lugarparticipacion) {
    $this->lugarparticipacion = $lugarparticipacion;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get lugarparticipacion
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLugarparticipacion() {
    return $this->lugarparticipacion;
}

/**
 * Set fechainscritpcion
 *
 * @param \DateTime $fechainscritpcion
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setFechainscritpcion($fechainscritpcion) {
    $this->fechainscritpcion = $fechainscritpcion;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get fechainscritpcion
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getFechainscritpcion() {
    return $this->fechainscritpcion;
}

/**
 * Set ipinscripcion
 *
 * @param string $ipinscripcion
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setIpinscripcion($ipinscripcion) {
    $this->ipinscripcion = $ipinscripcion;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get ipinscripcion
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getIpinscripcion() {
    return $this->ipinscripcion;
}

/**
 * Set cadenaseg
 *
 * @param string $cadenaseg
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setCadenaseg($cadenaseg) {
    $this->cadenaseg = $cadenaseg;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get cadenaseg
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCadenaseg() {
    return $this->cadenaseg;
}

/**
 * Set bloqueo
 *
 * @param string $bloqueo
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setBloqueo($bloqueo) {
    $this->bloqueo = $bloqueo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get bloqueo
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getBloqueo() {
    return $this->bloqueo;
}

/**
 * Set razonBloqueo
 *
 * @param string $razonBloqueo
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setRazonBloqueo($razonBloqueo) {
    $this->razonBloqueo = $razonBloqueo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get razonBloqueo
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRazonBloqueo() {
    return $this->razonBloqueo;
}

/**
 * Set perfil
 *
 * @param string $perfil
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setPerfil($perfil) {
    $this->perfil = $perfil;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get perfil
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPerfil() {
    return $this->perfil;
}

/**
 * Set fechaControl
 *
 * @param \DateTime $fechaControl
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setFechaControl($fechaControl) {
    $this->fechaControl = $fechaControl;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get fechaControl
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getFechaControl() {
    return $this->fechaControl;
}

/**
 * Set idMunicipio
 *
 * @param integer $idMunicipio
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setIdMunicipio($idMunicipio) {
    $this->idMunicipio = $idMunicipio;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idMunicipio
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getIdMunicipio() {
    return $this->idMunicipio;
}

/**
 * Set idProvincia
 *
 * @param integer $idProvincia
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setIdProvincia($idProvincia) {
    $this->idProvincia = $idProvincia;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idProvincia
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getIdProvincia() {
    return $this->idProvincia;
}

/**
 * Set idCcaa
 *
 * @param string $idCcaa
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setIdCcaa($idCcaa) {
    $this->idCcaa = $idCcaa;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idCcaa
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getIdCcaa() {
    return $this->idCcaa;
}

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $imagenes;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $validaInscritos;

/**
 * @var \BackendBundle\Entity\Ccaa
 */
private $ccaaInscritos;

/**
 * @var \BackendBundle\Entity\Municipios
 */
private $municipioInscritos;

/**
 * @var \BackendBundle\Entity\Provincia
 */
private $provinciaInscritos;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct() {
    $this->imagenes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->validaInscritos = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add imagene
 *
 * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\InscritosImages $imagene
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function addImagene(\BackendBundle\Entity\InscritosImages $imagene) {
    $this->imagenes[] = $imagene;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove imagene
 *
 * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\InscritosImages $imagene
 */
public function removeImagene(\BackendBundle\Entity\InscritosImages $imagene) {
    $this->imagenes->removeElement($imagene);
}

/**
 * Get imagenes
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getImagenes() {
    return $this->imagenes;
}

/**
 * Add validaInscrito
 *
 * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\ValidaInscritos $validaInscrito
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function addValidaInscrito(\BackendBundle\Entity\ValidaInscritos $validaInscrito) {
    $this->validaInscritos[] = $validaInscrito;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove validaInscrito
 *
 * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\ValidaInscritos $validaInscrito
 */
public function removeValidaInscrito(\BackendBundle\Entity\ValidaInscritos $validaInscrito) {
    $this->validaInscritos->removeElement($validaInscrito);
}

/**
 * Get validaInscritos
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getValidaInscritos() {
    return $this->validaInscritos;
}

/**
 * Set ccaaInscritos
 *
 * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\Ccaa $ccaaInscritos
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setCcaaInscritos(\BackendBundle\Entity\Ccaa $ccaaInscritos = null) {
    $this->ccaaInscritos = $ccaaInscritos;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get ccaaInscritos
 *
 * @return \BackendBundle\Entity\Ccaa
 */
public function getCcaaInscritos() {
    return $this->ccaaInscritos;
}

/**
 * Set municipioInscritos
 *
 * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\Municipios $municipioInscritos
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setMunicipioInscritos(\BackendBundle\Entity\Municipios $municipioInscritos = null) {
    $this->municipioInscritos = $municipioInscritos;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get municipioInscritos
 *
 * @return \BackendBundle\Entity\Municipios
 */
public function getMunicipioInscritos() {
    return $this->municipioInscritos;
}

/**
 * Set provinciaInscritos
 *
 * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\Provincia $provinciaInscritos
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function setProvinciaInscritos(\BackendBundle\Entity\Provincia $provinciaInscritos = null) {
    $this->provinciaInscritos = $provinciaInscritos;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get provinciaInscritos
 *
 * @return \BackendBundle\Entity\Provincia
 */
public function getProvinciaInscritos() {
    return $this->provinciaInscritos;
}

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $inscritosAcciones;

/**
 * Add inscritosAccione
 *
 * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\InscritosAcciones $inscritosAccione
 *
 * @return Inscritos
 */
public function addInscritosAccione(\BackendBundle\Entity\InscritosAcciones $inscritosAccione) {
    $this->inscritosAcciones[] = $inscritosAccione;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove inscritosAccione
 *
 * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\InscritosAcciones $inscritosAccione
 */
public function removeInscritosAccione(\BackendBundle\Entity\InscritosAcciones $inscritosAccione) {
    $this->inscritosAcciones->removeElement($inscritosAccione);
}

/**
 * Get inscritosAcciones
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getInscritosAcciones() {
    return $this->inscritosAcciones;
}

}
```

entity InscritosAcciones

```
 namespace BackendBundle\Entity;

/**
 * InscritosAcciones
 */
class InscritosAcciones
{
/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $status;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $accion;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $datos;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $fecha = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $inscritosId;

/**
 * @var \BackendBundle\Entity\Inscritos
 */
private $inscritos;

/**
 * @var \BackendBundle\Entity\Acciones
 */
private $acciones;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set status
 *
 * @param integer $status
 *
 * @return InscritosAcciones
 */
public function setStatus($status)
{
    $this->status = $status;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get status
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->status;
}

/**
 * Set accion
 *
 * @param string $accion
 *
 * @return InscritosAcciones
 */
public function setAccion($accion)
{
    $this->accion = $accion;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get accion
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAccion()
{
    return $this->accion;
}

/**
 * Set datos
 *
 * @param string $datos
 *
 * @return InscritosAcciones
 */
public function setDatos($datos)
{
    $this->datos = $datos;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get datos
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDatos()
{
    return $this->datos;
}

/**
 * Set fecha
 *
 * @param \DateTime $fecha
 *
 * @return InscritosAcciones
 */
public function setFecha($fecha)
{
    $this->fecha = $fecha;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get fecha
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getFecha()
{
    return $this->fecha;
}

/**
 * Set inscritosId
 *
 * @param integer $inscritosId
 *
 * @return InscritosAcciones
 */
public function setInscritosId($inscritosId)
{
    $this->inscritosId = $inscritosId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get inscritosId
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getInscritosId()
{
    return $this->inscritosId;
}

/**
 * Set inscritos
 *
 * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\Inscritos $inscritos
 *
 * @return InscritosAcciones
 */
public function setInscritos(\BackendBundle\Entity\Inscritos $inscritos = null)
{
    $this->inscritos = $inscritos;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get inscritos
 *
 * @return \BackendBundle\Entity\Inscritos
 */
public function getInscritos()
{
    return $this->inscritos;
}

/**
 * Set acciones
 *
 * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\Acciones $acciones
 *
 * @return InscritosAcciones
 */
public function setAcciones(\BackendBundle\Entity\Acciones $acciones = null)
{
    $this->acciones = $acciones;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get acciones
 *
 * @return \BackendBundle\Entity\Acciones
 */
public function getAcciones()
{
    return $this->acciones;
}
}
```

Both tables are related to other tables but are not necessary in this query. The incritosAcciones table is related to a table of actions, and the one of inscribed with enough tables since it is a quite complex structure.
    
Regarding what result gives me, because I think I had previously put it, I list all the rows of the inscribed table since they will always have more shares (something in the status field) besides the status = 8

Finally, if in the consultation I group it by
     ->groupBy("u.status")
I only get (normal) one record for each of the statuses except the one that has status 8

a full consultation would be

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from("BackendBundle:Inscritos", "e")
            ->select("e")
             ->innerJoin("BackendBundle:InscritosAcciones", "u", "WITH", "e.id=u.inscritosId")
             ->groupBy("u.status")
            ->where("u.status != 8")
            ->getQuery();
```

I have added two screenshots of my phpmyAdmin that you can see in the Spanish version because here I do not have enough reputation to upload images

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/132649/problema-para-que-no-salga-un-usuario-en-consulta-onetomany-si-se-da-una-condici

And what they would have to leave are users 43 and 63, nothing would happen because the other users left who do not have any action yet, but the one who should never leave is user 1, who has an action with status 8

Can someone help me please.

Thank you

Comment: If you are expecting InscritosEntity you shouldn't use a `group by`.Can you replace also `where()` by `andWhere()`?

Comment: I have already found the solution, many thanks to goto for his help with his comment
The error comes because of my lack of knowledge of Doctrine and to keep thinking about doing the consultations as I have always done before.
the correct consultation has to be done without the groupby and it would be    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->from("BackendBundle:Inscritos", "e")
                ->select("e")
                ->innerJoin("BackendBundle:InscritosAcciones", "u", "WITH", "e.id=u.inscritosId")
                ->where("u.status != 2")
                ->getQuery();